# Jackson + Tomcat - java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class

Tags: java, json, tomcat, tomcat6, jackson

I have a Java webservice running in Tomcat 6 which accepts JSON input. I am trying to use Jackson ObjectMapper to parse the input json. But when initializing the ObjectMapper object I am getting this error

```
16:08:13,616 ERROR [[jersey]] Servlet.service() for servlet jersey threw exception                                                                                                                        
java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class                                                                                                                                                    
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)                                                                                                                                                  
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)                                                                                                                                        
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)                                                                                                                                            
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)                                                                                                                            
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2733)                                                                                                        
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1124)                                                                                                                
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1612)                                                                                                                
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)                                                                                                                
    at com.test.project.offline.ws.WsApiResource.updateData(WsApiResource.java:169) 
.......
```

At line 169 I have this         `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();`

When calling com.test.project.offline.ws.WsApiResource.updateData() method locally in a unit test it works without any error.

Kindly help me in fixing this. I am using Jackson 1.8.4 and tomcat 6.

UPDATE: Fixed the issue. Problem was a different version of jackson in the dependency tree. Excluding it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I also had the same issue with Apache Lucene. I had lucene-core-3.6.0.jar and lucene-core-3.5.0.jar in my /WEB-INF/lib folder. Removing one or the other also fixed my problem. It must be a versioning issue.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with Apache Solr, and it was resolved by deleting my `~/.m2` cache.

This issue was also caused by specifying the wrong version of a dependency in my `pom.xml` file, where another package was automatically downloading another version.

Maven really should have some sort of conflicting versions of dependency resolution scheme...

Answer (score 1):

The same for me - my ejb3 application uses jackson-all-1.9.4 - and my glassfish container (v2.1) contains a lib/jackson-asl-0.9.4.jar:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
```

Now, I have replaced jackson-all with gson.

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 0):

Neil has a great answer to this question. However, aside from your M2 cache, check if you're a complete DUMMY like I WAS and ensure your POM doesn't include two packages where the same Final class is declared. Google API's are notorious for cross including classes in their API Jars. Ensure you delete EVERYTHING you don't need!